# Content full width, only after fixed height sidebar

Tags: html, css

**I'm trying to achieve a layout similar to this**:

[image: Example layout to achieve]

Where:

- Each content block has multiple elements inside of it
- Content blocks and sidebar height is variable
- Not using javascript

The closest I've got is this (but notice how the articles before the sidebar ends occupy much more space than desired, and buttons in the 3rd article occupy 100% of the page while the rest of the article's content occupy less):

```css
.page {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 410px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

article {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
  h3 { margin: 0; }
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define width for first 3 article divs.

```css
.page {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 527px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

article {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
  h3 { margin: 0; }
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.small-box-content{
    width: 67%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <article class="small-box-content">
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="small-box-content">
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="small-box-content">
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but you are missing the point "Content blocks and sidebar height is variable". What if sidebar height is enough to span 4 articles? Or if only two articles are enough to cover the whole sidebar...

Comment: @AlejoAnibal you mean your sidebar height increase dynamically?. So according to it you want to set articles width?

Comment: Not dinamically, but the client will manage the content, and I don't know what that content will be, and it can be changed periodically, so asking him which will be the content is not an option

Answer (score 0):

please let me know this is what you want
 Just added new div class for three article **.side_left**

```
    .page {
      width: 1000px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .side_left{
    width:650px;
    }
    .sidebar {
      float: right;
      width: 300px;
      height: 420px;
      margin-top:20px;
      background: red;
    }

    .content {
      padding-right: 20px;
    }

    article {
      background: #cdcdcd;
      padding: 15px;
width:100%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      h3 { margin: 0; }
  

    .buttons {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    <div class="page">
      <div class="sidebar"></div>
      <div class="content">
 <div class="side_left">
        <article>
          <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button>btn1</button>
            <button>btn2</button>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button>btn1</button>
            <button>btn2</button>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button>btn1</button>
            <button>btn2</button>
          </div>
        </article>
</div>
        <article>
          <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button>btn1</button>
            <button>btn2</button>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button>btn1</button>
            <button>btn2</button>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos non nostrum distinctio officia aliquid maxime doloremque harum id consequuntur quo.</p>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button>btn1</button>
            <button>btn2</button>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but you are missing the point "Content blocks and sidebar height is variable". What if sidebar height is enough to span 4 articles? Or if only two articles are enough to cover the whole sidebar...

Comment: Sidebar height will not necessarily be 410px as the example. It was for demonstrative purposes, but its height can vary depending on its content. Same for the articles, their height will vary according to their content, so it's not right to take for granted that three articles will occupy sidebar height. Maybe two articles, maybe four, and maybe more... That's something I can not know

Comment: so its important that sidebar and article height for three or four as per your wish need to be equal

Comment: That's a very old thought. Content can vary and also responsiveness can change elements height.